# TI-BASIC interpreter for Fishstacks

Tags: ti-basic, interpreter

[Fishstacks](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fishstacks) is a [deadfish](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish) derivative based on a stack the stack can only hold four elements when a fifth element is pushed the bottom element is kicked out and eventually printed out to the screen.

I've come up with an interpreter in TI-BASIC for my calculator. However, I fell slightly guilty about using all four variables `ABCD`. I wonder if there could be a better way? Maybe with lists (arrays). I've just started learning about them, so I don't feel confident switching over yet. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Also, in order not to push anything to the screen until something falls off the stack, I've had to initialize variables to `-2`. This is the main reason I have not converted to arrays yet; I don't see how they could address this issue. (maybe even throw a `DOMAIN` error).

```
:ClrHome
:Disp "FISHSTACKS IDSP","INTERPRETER"
:0->I
:-2->A
:A->B
:B->C
:C->D
:Input Str1
:While I<length(Str1)
:I+1->I
:sub(Str1,I,1)->Str2
:If Str2="I"
:A+1->A
:If Str2="D"
:A-1->A
:If Str2="S"
:A^2->A
:If Str2="P" and D>-1
:Then
:Disp D
:C->D
:B->C
:A->B
:0->A
:End
:If A=256 or A=-1
:0->A
:If A=-2
:Stop
:End
```

By convention, I've represented the `STO→` character, `→` with `->`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was asked by @Timtech to join + post an improvement. Using arrays is a lot easier to understand, and there were so many optimizations that I decided to completely re-write the code. I'm sure it could be improved by other advanced programmers like me, as I'm using several long expressions here... note that `L1` represents list #1 (`2nd` + `1` on the calculator) and `~` is the negative token.

```
:ClrHome
:Disp "FISHSTACKS IDSP","INTERPRETER
:DelVar IInput Str1
:DelVar L1~{2,2,2,2→L1
:While I<length(Str1
:I+1→I
:sub(Str1,I,1→Str2
:(Str2="I")-(Str2="D
:Ans+L1(4→L1(4
:If Str2="S
:L1(4)²→L1(4
:If Str2="P
:Then
:L1(1
:If 2+Ans
:Disp Ans
:ΔList(cumSum(L1->L1
:0->L1(4
:End
:L1(4
:If Ans=256 or Ans<0
:0->L1(4
:End
```

**Improvements**

1. Saved bytes by removing several unneeded ending parentheses and quotes
2. Used `DelVar` since it does not need a following colon
3. Used an array instead of four variables
4. Used a complex expression `:(Str2="I")-(Str2="D` saved to `Ans` to save space
5. Used `ΔList(cumSum(L1->L1` to get `L1` minus its first element
6. Several others I'm not listing due to their minisculity; mainly using `Ans` to save space and speed

Comment: Wow great, I'm glad you could make it! Enjoy your stay.

Comment: Thanks @Timtech, I'll probably be answering your other questions in the near future, whenever I have the time.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!

Comment: Haha, that good old TI-BASIC where not closing the parenthesis and the strings is the norm :D

Answer (score 14):

Beyond the bad names that you are already aware of, I see a few things that could be improved.

`str1` and `str2` are bad variable names as well. They should be `str` and `chr` respectively. Those names would properly represent the data and make this code much more understandable. It would be instantly clear to anyone looking at the code that you're looping through each character of the string the user inputs.

This section of code makes no sense.

> ```
> :If Str2="P" and D>-1
> :Then
> :Disp D
> :C->D
> :B->C
> :A->C
> :0->A
> :End
> ```

Translated into a "normal" basic language, it looks like this.

```
    If char = "P" And d > -1 Then
        Print d

        d = c
        c = b
        c = a
        a = 0
    End If
```

And it is instantly obvious that you only need to make the assignment to `c` once.

```
:If Str2="P" and D>-1
:Then
:Disp D
:C->D
:A->C
:0->A
:End
```

The other improvement I can see here, is that I think it makes a lot of sense to use a [For Loop](http://www.ticalc.org/programming/columns/83plus-bas/cherny/#for) instead of a While loop here. That way you wouldn't have to increment `I` manually on every iteration of the loop. It would make this little program a little cleaner.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like you are not familiar with the language; other than catching the typo, there's really no improvements. Strings cannot be renamed, For( loops take more space, etc.

Comment: I'm not very familiar @Timtech. I was working from the documentation, but even if a For loop takes more space, I still feel it would be a better option as you wouldn't have to manually increment the loop.

Comment: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/for

Comment: Yes. I read that earlier when writing the review. You're under no obligation to take my advice @Timtech, but I stand by my advice.

Comment: Okay then, sorry for the harshness initially... I've asked some other friends to try to optimize it, hopefully I can get some  better input...

Comment: I ope so too! And the bounty is open for another week, so maybe someone here will take notice. =)

Comment: Yep, one of my friends says he's writing up one now.

Comment: TI calculators have RAM on the order of kilobytes. Short variable names are the norm.

Comment: @200_success I did some quick research and updated my answer. Does that look better?

Comment: Well, the remark about string names is still pointless: you can't name variables in TI-BASIC. There are like a dozen of string variables named `Str1`, `Str2`, `Str3`... and you can't do anything about it. You have to use these cryptic names.

Comment: @200_success TI-Basic is a tokenized language, which means that there are only a certain amount of variables, and they are already a certain size (1 or 2 bytes) when referenced in the code.

Comment: @Morwenn, there are `Str1` to `Str9` plus `Str0`, so 10 (if you want to be exact).

Answer (score 5):

```
:ClrHome
:Disp "FISHSTACKS IDSP","INTERPRETER"
:-{2,2,2,0->L1
:Input Str1
:For(I,1,length(Str1
:sub(Str1,I,1
:If Ans≠"P"
:Then
:(Ans="I")-(Ans="D")+L1(4)^int(e^(Ans="S"->L1(4
:If Ans≥0 and Ans≠256
:Else
:L1(1
:If 2+Ans
:Disp Ans
:augment(ΔList(cumSum(L1)),{0->L1
:End
:End
```

I was able to shorten FlyAwayBirdie's answer even more by combining some expressions, moving the overflow checking earlier to take advantage of Ans, setting L1 in fewer bytes, using a For loop, and a couple of other things. Additionally, I initialized variables to -1 instead of -2, except for the initial accumulator which starts at 0 as per the spec.

You can remove the close quotes at the ends of the lines.

Edit: Saved a couple more bytes by not saving the substring to Str2.

Edit: Fixed overflow functionality; however, undefined commands will now be recognized as "P".

Comment: Nice! Usually when he posts it's hard to improve upon it :P